# SQL Server reports with charts

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting

Does anyone have any recommendation on generating reports for SQL Server databases?
I used the report builder wizard and other than generating some columns with data, I was wondering what other free packages or addons I can use to generate graphs or charts along with the table results from report builder.

Any site or url links appreciated.

Using SQL Server 2005 and 2008 on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

Report Builder 2.0 can create charts as well as text output, and a mix of the two.

You also should look at Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), which can be installed with SQL Server 2005 or 2008 and will give you a report creation tool to use with Sql Server Reporting Services [(SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173745.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[sqldashboards](http://www.sqldashboards.com/) allows creating reports and generating charts straight from a sql server database. You can either use the java app to build a dashboard or the command line tool to generate the images and bring the report together yourself. Depends how much control you want.